# ImportHtml with HTTP POST method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, http-post

Is it possible to use `HTTP` `POST` method with `ImportHtml` function? It seems to be doing only `GET` method.

I need `POST` to retrieve results from a web page that are normally (for "human user") shown after filling simple form. And that form is then `POST`ed. I would like to simulate this with `ImportHtml` to get the results. (Yes, I already asked web page administrator to release the data in XML format or something like that but I would not count on this being done...)

Comment: I asked the same question at Google Product Forums (http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/topic/docs/cU8VK_UpEUc/discussion) but got no answer at all after a long time so I'm trying my luck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Google Apps Script's UrlFetch to post data and use the results in a spreadsheet. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp

Use Xml.parse to parse it (use the lenient option to get html). Here's the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_xml#parse) and a [relevant post from the old forum](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/topic/apps-script/jlFsJIRcPhw/discussion).

Comment: I expected this would be doable with Scripts. Yet I hoped that maybe it could be avoided... Thanks anyway!

Comment: OK One more thing. I will get an HTML page. Now how to deal with it (parse it)? `ImportHtml` does it for me. But I didn't see any service in Google Apps Script that would do the parsing.

Comment: @Adam I added the parse info to my answer.

Comment: @AdamBadura please accept this answer if it indeed answers your question or let us know what further you need.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to but first I wanted to finish what I wanted to achieve so that if there are any other questions on the process I will ask them first (like the above) as with Google Apps Script you have to do manually what `ImportHtml` did for you.

Comment: Using Xml service you can parse the HTML yourself. It is a bit difficult and error prone but doable.